# I am working photo upload for android

Tags: android, image, upload, gallery

Presently working for photo upload after selecing image.The selected image should open in new screen . How to do it..
my code is

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v==btncamera){
            Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
            startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
        }

        else if(v==btngallery){
            Intent intentImage = new Intent();
            intentImage.setType("image/*");
            intentImage.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intentImage,"Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
            setContentView(R.layout.kanga3);
        }
    }
     protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
            if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) { 
                Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            }  
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("mybitmap",photo);
startActivity(intent);

On Second Activity....

Intent i =getIntent();
Bitmap bitmap= (Bitmap) i.getParcelableExtra("mybitmap");
```

Like this...      http://android-coding.blogspot.in/2011/01/how-to-passing-bitmap-between.html

Comment: Thank you,while selecting images from gallery some of them are selecting and others has no response